# How to make CALayer adapt to the application appearance using drawlayer:inContext:?

Tags: objective-c, calayer, nsview

I have a layer-*hosting* `NSView` subclass that draws itself using a `CALayer` object set as its `layer`. Since it's not a layer-backed view, it doesn't redraw during `drawRect:` nor during `updateLayer`, but during `drawLayer:inContext:` after I call `setNeedsDisplay` on its layer.

The problem is that the layer must adapt to the application appearance (it uses system `NSColor` objects), and appkit doesn't seem to manage this situation.
Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/appearance_customization/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface?language=objc) that one needs to set the layer's content during `drawRect:` or `updateLayer`, otherwise the colors don't adapt to the appearance.
Indeed, they don't update in `drawLayer:inContext:`

The current (ugly) solution I use is to call `-display` directly on the layer (which Apple says I should not do) within the `updateLayer` method (of another view since the view hosting the layer isn't send `updateLayer`, given that it's not a layer-backed view).

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the layer rather than `display` does not work, as the layer would not redraw its content within the `updateLayer` call, but after.

Is there another solution?

Comment: It would be easier to get help on this if you provide a [mre].

Comment: No I don't think it would since it's not a problem with my code. I'm looking for a solution to make a CALayer that draws its contents adapt to the application appearance. What I do in drawLayer:inContext is irrelevant.